# Addition of a number to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
     float a=10;
     float* p=&a;
    printf("%u\n",p);
     p=p+3;
     printf("%u",p);
}
```

After execution of this program I got 2 memory addresses as an output, thelatter with a value greater by 12 than the former.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
     float a=10;
     float* p=&a;
    printf("%u\n",p);
     p=p+3.5;
     printf("%u",p);
}
```

I tried changing 3 to 3.5 but I got an output with equal values of both the addresses. I expected that the value would increment at least by 12 in either cases. 
What could be the reason ?

Comment: `p=p+3;` is undefined behavior, and `p=p+3.5;` does not make sense and should not compile. And to print the address use `"%p"`.

Comment: @iharob Its like incrementing the address of the variable (inside the pointer) by 3 time the size of a single int type variable I read it in a book called "Let Us C"

Comment: See the answer to see why `p = p + 3` is incorrect in your case and even dangerous. And `p + 3.5` makes no sense, if you want such effect probably you should `((char *)p) + 14`. If `sizeof(*p) == 4`, it will have the meaning I think you believe `p + 3.5` has.

Comment: "`p=p+3;` is undefined behavior". That doesn't sound right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how pointer arithmetic works. It's designed to work on arrays.

```
float array[4];
float *q;
q = array; /* Now q points to the first element of the array: q == &array[0] */
printf("%p\n", q);
q += 3; /* Now q points to the fourth element of the array: q == &array[3] */
printf("%p\n", q);
```

When you add an integer to a pointer, it points that many elements further into the array. If the size of the array elements is N bytes, then adding x to a pointer adds x*N to the address.

On your machine, it appears that `sizeof(float)` is 4: you see that x*N=12, with x=3, so N=4.

Note that there are several errors in your code. In your program, `p=p+3` has undefined behavior because `p` points to a single float (which has the same memory layout as an array of 1 float). It is an error to make a pointer point outside the boundaries of an object. On a typical PC compiler you just silently get an invalid pointer; a rare few implementations would detect the invalid pointer as soon as it's computed and abort the program with an error.

Printing the pointer value with `%u` is also an error. In practice it may work, print garbage, or crash, depending on your compiler and on whether pointers have the same size as `unsigned int`. Any halfway decent compiler would warn you that `printf("%u", p)` is incorrect; if yours doesn't, make sure to enable its useful warnings (e.g. `gcc -O -Wall` if you're using GCC).

Comment: @haccks In the original program, it does.

Comment: No. There is no dereferncing in original program. So, no UB.

Comment: @haccks If you make a pointer point outside of an object (except immediately at the end of the object, which is valid), then the behavior is undefined. Most C programmers only ever work with implementations that use a flat memory model and don't trap on pointer arithmetic, but pointer arithmetic does have undefined behavior if the pointer goes out of the allowed range, even if the pointer isn't dereferenced.

Comment: Then may be I am missing something here. Any relevant quote from standard?

Comment: @haccks: It's UB (no need to dereference). See C11 6.5.6/p8: `If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.`

Answer (score 4):

There is only three types of pointer arithmetic is allowed in C:

- Adding an integer to a pointer.
- Subtracting an integer from a pointer.
- Subtracting one pointer from another (they should point to same array).

Standard says that:

#### C11:6.5.6 Additive operators:

> 2 For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or **one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type**. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)
>
> 3 For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic type;
>   — **both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete object types**; or
>   — **the left operand is a pointer to a complete object type and the right operand has integer type**.

Any other arithmetic operation is invalid and will invoke undefined behavior. Note that the correct specifier for printing address is `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
the program contains several errors and poor programing practices

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    float a=10; // init floats with float values, so use '10.0f'
    float* p=&a;
    printf("%u\n",p); // print addresses with '%p' not '%u'
    p=p+3;        // now 'p' is pointed to some unknown area
    printf("%u",p); // print addresses with '%p' not '%u'
}

good thing the code did not 'de-reference' 'p' after 'p'
was modified, because that would have been undefined behaviour
possibly leading to a seg fault event
```